# Записать побайтно в файл из итератора (.bytes)

Tags: rust

```
for byte in abc.bytes() {
            /* ~~~ */
}
```

`.bytes` возвращает u8, нужно записать побайтно в файл (или stdout - без разницы). Пробовал плясать с `BufWriter`, но как-то не получается. Все возможности записи (`write()`, `write_all()`..) рассчитаны на массив. Может можно как-нибудь создать буфер и наполнять его байтами, которые уже отправляются?

Answer (score 2):

Лучше конечно писать через буфер, `Vec<u8>` здесь сам напрашивается. Но можно использовать `write()` для записи по одному байту.

Вот пример - копирование по одному байту из вектора `vi` в `vo`  с прибавлением числа `10`:

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let mut vo:Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    let vi:Vec<u8> = vec!(1, 2, 3, 4);
    for b in vi.bytes(){
        match b{
            Ok(v) => if vo.write(&[v+10]).unwrap_or(0) == 0 { break },
            _ => break
        };
    }
    println!("{:?}",vo);
}
```

Точно так же можно писать не в вектор, а в файл.

---

Пример записи через буфер:

```
use std::io::{Read, Write};

const BUF_SIZE:usize=3;

fn main() {
    let mut buf:Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(BUF_SIZE);
    let vi:Vec<u8> = vec!(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    let mut vo:Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    for b in vi.bytes(){
        match b{
            Ok(v) => {
                buf.push(v+10);
                if buf.len() == BUF_SIZE {
                    if vo.write(&buf).unwrap_or(0) == 0 { 
                        buf.clear(); 
                        break; 
                    }else{
                        buf.clear();
                    };
                };                
            },
            _ => break
        };
    }
    if buf.len()!=0 { vo.write(&buf).unwrap_or(0);}
    println!("{:?}", vo);
}
```

То же самое, но короче за счет использования итераторов:

```
use std::io::{Read, Write};

const BUF_SIZE:usize=3;

fn main() {
    let vi:Vec<u8> = vec!(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    let mut vo:Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    let mut vii = vi.bytes();

    loop{
        let buf:Vec<u8> = vii.by_ref()
            .take_while(|x| x.is_ok())
            .take(BUF_SIZE)
            .map(|x| x.unwrap()+10)
            .collect();

        if vo.write(&buf).unwrap_or(0) < BUF_SIZE { break };
    }
    println!("{:?}", vo);
}
```

Comment: Как лучше загонять байт в функцию: по ссылке или через копирование? Байт мал, с ссылкой знатный оверхед будет, по-моему. Что получаем в вашем случае: мы считываем байты, загоняем в вектор-буффер, оттуда пишем в stdout/файл, обращаясь к байтам по ссылке. Но как оно будет по сравнению с побайтным считыванием и записыванием в stdout/файл в представлении среза массива `.write(&[byte])` для каждого байта?

Comment: @Андрей не совсем ясно про "как оно будет по сравнению с побайтным считыванием". Как оно будет "по эффективности"?

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего писать побайтно в `BufWriter` с помощью нехитрого приема: создать временный массив из одного байта на стеке и взять на него ссылку.

```
let mut writer = BufWriter::new(output);
for byte in abc.bytes() {
    writer.write_all(&[byte]).unwrap();
}
```

Для лучшей эффективности можно попоробовать собрать байты в вектор:

```
let v: Vec<_> = abc.bytes().collect();
writer.write_all(&v[..]).expect("write failed");
```

Если последовательность итератора может оказаться большой или неограниченной, можно читать его блоками:

```
let mut v = Vec::<u8>::new();
let mut iter = abc.bytes();
loop {
    v.extend(iter.by_ref().take(BLOCK_SIZE));
    if v.len() == 0 {
        break;
    }
    writer.write_all(&v[..]).unwrap();
    v.clear();
}
```